# How to write a single line of code to trigger ComboBox drop down for all ComboBoxes in Visual Basic VS 2022?

Tags: for-loop, combobox

hi everyone i have a form which contains a lot of comboboxes
and i'm writing
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Click
ComboBox1.DroppedDown = True
End Sub
code for all of comboboxes
how can i write one code for all ComboBoxes do for same thing
for all comboboxes.click event than all comboboxes.DroppedDown = true
in visual basic vs 2022 ?

i'm trying to  simple code for all off these codes below

for example

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Click
    ComboBox1.DroppedDown = True
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.Click
    ComboBox2.DroppedDown = True
End Sub
```

.....